# Parse.com. Push notification with long alert not received

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm developing Windows Phone 8 app and use Parse.com for send Push Notification

The issue is when I send JSON-message like this:

{ "alert": "Artem Flotsky commented commented commented commented commented commented commented commented commented commented your number", "title": "TestApp!!!" }

it isn't received by phone, while message like this:

{ "alert": "Artem Flotsky commented your number", "title": "TestApp!!!" }

received correctly.

But, initially, I came into this issue trying to send message with non-english (russian) symbols:

{ "alert": "Artem Flotsky откомментировал твой номер", "title": "TestApp!!!" }

it also wasn't received. In the same time, a little shorter message

{ "alert": "Artem Flotsky лайкнул твой номер", "title": "TestApp!!!" }

received with no trouble.

Are there any additional limits to message content I could miss?